# Best way to protect file python?

Tags: python, file

I want to protect a file , i don't allow user can change it (only my app can change this) and can't delete. I know Windows Defender but it's not work perfect.
I like something like this:
first i have a txt file, this file's name is sample.txt

```
from protector import protect_with_lock
protect(file="sample.txt",password_lock="12345")
```

after i run this code this folder is emty.

```
from protector import unlock
unlock(file="sample.txt",password_lock="12345")
```

and this file is come back
Thanks for help!

Comment: IMHO, Python is irrelevant here as it's the OS's job to protect files, and the very notion of this "protection" is provided by the OS/file system.

Comment: i want something like "locking this file"

Comment: You could have a look at [`os.chmod`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/os.html#os.chmod)

Comment: So, i want hiding this file - but normal hide in windows is very bad, any way?

Comment: If you just simply open the file it cannot be removed before the file handle is released (or your app is closed). I mean: `f = open(file)`. Is that enough "protection" for you? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, ```open(file)``` is work. But when my app close then user can delete it.

Answer (score 2):

On any system, what a process can do only depends on the user id and not on the application. What you want would only be possible on a Unix-like where an application can run under a specific user thanks to the *set user id* feature. On Windows, the only possible way is to split the application :

- a back end service running under a dedicated user that will own and edit the file
- a front end application for user interaction that will *communicate* with the back end service. BTW this is now the best practices way, even on Unix like systems.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Lock and hide a folder.

1. ) Put your file inside a folder.
2. ) Get into that folder and create a new text file and name it anything.
3. ) Copy paste the below code inside the text file:

```
    
    @ECHO OFF
    
    title Folder Locker
    
    if EXIST "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" goto UNLOCK
    
    if NOT EXIST Locker goto MDLOCKER
    
    :CONFIRM
    
    echo Are you sure u want to Lock the folder(Y/N)
    
    set/p "cho=>"
    
    if %cho%==Y goto LOCK
    
    if %cho%==y goto LOCK
    
    if %cho%==n goto END
    
    if %cho%==N goto END
    
    echo Invalid choice.
    
    goto CONFIRM
    
    :LOCK
    
    ren Locker "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
    
    attrib +h +s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
    
    echo Folder locked
    
    goto End
    
    :UNLOCK
    
    echo Enter password to Unlock folder
    
    set/p "pass=>"
    
    if NOT %pass%==Enter-Your-Password-Here goto FAIL
    
    attrib -h -s "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}"
    
    ren "Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}" Locker
    
    echo Folder Unlocked successfully
    
    goto End
    
    :FAIL
    
    echo Invalid password
    
    goto end
    
    :MDLOCKER
    
    md Locker
    
    echo Locker created successfully
    
    goto End
    
         :End
```

4. ) Find for 'Enter-Your-Password-Here' inside the file and replace it with your password for the file.
5. ) Click on file menu on the left most corner and click on 'Save As...'
6. ) Add '.bat' extension to the filename. For ex : if the filename is locker.txt, then make it locker.bat.
7. ) Click on save and save the file.
8. ) Double click on the locker.bat file. A locker folder will appear.
9. ) Place all the files to be locked in to that folder.
10. ) Double click on the locker.bat file again.
11. ) A command prompt will open. It will ask if you want to lock the folder.Type Y and press enter.
12. ) Whenever you want to open the folder, double click on the locker.bat file again. Enter the password and press enter.
13. ) The folder will reappear.
14. ) To lock the folder again, repeat step 10 and step 11.
    Let me know if you get stuck somewhere.